# How do I toggle the torch light by using the proximity sensor?

Tags: ios, swift, proximity

So far in my code, I am able to turn on the torch light when the proximity sensor is enabled, but I am having trouble adjusting my code to make it so that when the proximity is disabled, the torch light turns off.

```
func proximityChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let device = notification.object as? UIDevice {
    print("\(device) detected!")
    toggleTorch(on: true)
    } else { 
//This is the line of code I need help with specifically.
        toggleTorch(on: false)
    }
}

func activateProximitySensor() {
    let device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
    device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = true
    if device.proximityMonitoringEnabled {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "proximityChanged:", name: "UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification", object: device)

    }
}

func toggleTorch(on on: Bool) {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if on == true {
                device.torchMode = .On
            } else {
                device.torchMode = .Off
            }

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch { 
            print("Torch could not be used")
        }
    } else {
        print("Torch is not available")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `object` in the notification will *always* be the UIDevice, so your test is pointless. The problem is that you are not checking whether the user is proximate or not. Having receive a reference to the device you need to check its `proximityState` property; *that* is the basis you need for your test.

Comment: How would I check for the proximityState property.  Would I replace my function for toggleTorch with a check proximityState property?  The apple literature isn't too specific on this either.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "apple literature". Just read the documentation on the UIDevice class. I'm not going to write your code for you.